# user authority level in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, authentication

I want every user have authority levels. 
Level 1 is customer level. 
Level 2 is manager level.

in the registeration function I ask; username, password and what level should user be and save in "users.txt". Here's a sample:

```
username pass 1
usereman ssap 2
nameuser psap 1
```

My login function:

```
def login():
print("\nYou're in login section")
username = input("Username: ")
password = input("Password: ")
for line in open("users.txt", "r").readlines():
    login_info = line.split()
    if username == login_info[0] and password == login_info[1]:
        if login_info[2] == 1:
            print("Dear customer, I'll take you to the marketplace.")
            return True
        elif login_info[2] == 2:
            print("Welcome manager!")
            return True
        else:
            print("Authority level is other than 1 or 2. Fix it!")
            welcome()
```

but every time I login it goes else part. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I corrected like this

```
            if login_info[2] == "1":
            print("Dear customer, I'll take you to the marketplace.")
            return True
            elif login_info[2] == "2":
            print("Welcome manager!")
            return True
```

it must be a string control